Why does the Braid Group on the 2-Sphere have the additional identity?
I was just wondering the geometric argument for why $B_m(S^2)$ has the relation:
$$\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_{m-2}\sigma_{m-2}\dots\sigma_2\sigma_1 = I$$
(Here is a depiction of the braid group of $m$ particles on the sphere)
I see that this is taking the first particle and wrapping it in front of everyone and then wrapping it behind everyone to return it to its starting spatial coordinate.
I'm not sure why we gain this extra relation when we go from a disk to the surface of a sphere. I'm trying to figure out how to "unbraid" this relation using the geometry of the sphere.
Is this just because we could lower the first particle in its z-coordinate (we couldn't do this with a disk), and then do this braiding as we increase the z-coord back to the starting z-coordinate of the other particles?
Picture of what I mean by this^

Your first picture only shows the first half $\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_{m-2}$, not the full thing. You can unbraid $\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_{m-2}\sigma_{m-2}\dots\sigma_2\sigma_1$ by sliding the first wire over the bottom of the sphere.

Doesn't the picture show the full thing though, if it was just the first half that would end up with particle 1 stopping at slot $m-1$?
I see what you mean about sliding the first wire along the bottom of the sphere though to undo the braid.

Your first picture is not a pure braid, so it can't be equal to the identity.

Oh the first picture was just supposed to be an example of a braid on $m$ particles. The second link was supposed to be a visualization of the identity. In any case I think your comment answers my question, so thank you!
